# An error occurred, please try again or try an alternate form of payment in Elavon Converge Credit Card Payment gateway

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a wordpress website. I am getting this error "An error occurred, please try again or try an alternate form of payment" while making payment in checkout. Right now the payment is on testing mode and I am using Elavon Converge Credit Card this gateway.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I have been trying to integrate the converge payment gateway with wordpress but nothing works out well. I have tried the Elavon-Payment-Gateway-for-WooCommerce-master and woo-virtual-merchant plugin for integration and at userflow while making payment error is displayed as Something went wrong while performing your request. Please contact website administrator to report this problem.
(Transaction Error) something is wrong.Mailed about this several times to Converge but didnt get any response, Dont know what to do

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem, everything is ok but Payment is not processing with same error.
My issue solved by enabling Force secure checkout from WooCommerce setting  page WooCommerce > Setting > Advanced

Answer (score 0):

I had this too. The solution for me was that the API# wasn't entered the same in both the card processing settings and the WooCommerce settings. Once fixed, good to go.

Answer (score 0):

That’s actually the Authorize.net plugin you’re using not playing well with optimizations. If you don’t want to completely disable defer, etc you can use the script exclusion functionality to leave only these out of those optiimzations.
We found that among the JS optimizations, ONLY minify will work with the Authorize.net plugin. If you try and use either combine JS or defer JS (alone or together), Authorize.net will not work in the checkout process and give you the error: “An error occurred, please try again or try an alternate form of payment”. When Authorize.net is installed, use only minify for JS optimizations.
[An error occurred, please try again or try an alternate form of payment](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/a-solution-to-common-authorize-net-problems-with-sg-optimizer/)